# PHP Recursive database loop

Tags: php, loops, recursion

I want to get the main parent of chosen subcategory. I made function which recursively loop the databasse and it even get the ID but I can only echo it. I cannot return it into variable. I need to work further with the returned ID. Here is my code.

```
public function check_parent($parent)
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('ci_categories', array('cat_id'=>$parent));
    $r = $q->row();
    if ($r->cat_child > 0)
    {
        $this->check_parent($r->cat_child);
    }   else {
        echo $parent;
    }
}
```

When I use return `$parent` in else I get null. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to return the value you should return it on both places

```
public function check_parent($parent)
{
$q = $this->db->get_where('ci_categories', array('cat_id'=>$parent));
$r = $q->row();
if ($r->cat_child > 0)
{
    return $this->check_parent($r->cat_child);
}   else {
    return $parent;
}
```

Comment: Such a simply answer. Thanks

Comment: Dont worry I would do it right now but there is 10minutes limit